# Customer product limit in NOP Commerce

Tags: nopcommerce

How can create number limit for products for each customer in NOP Commerce? For example, buyable number of product P for customer c be 10.

Comment: you can add a new attribute to customer for this and can manage the things from there.

Comment: Does it mean that the customer can not add more than 10 quantity of a product?

Comment: thanks for reply. yes, customer cannot add more than 10 quantity of a product and each product has it's limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some code to Nopcommerce source code that get product, user and user's limit for shopping product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Maximum cart qty* property in the Inventory section on the product detail page. It will restrict the customer and would not allow them to add more than the quantity defined at *Maximum cart qty* in the cart for each checkout.